# Magento 2 Commerce. What is up with the VersionControl Folders?

Tags: magento2.3.1, magento-2-commerce

I see a couple of VersionControl folders across Magento source code.

- Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl
- Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl
- Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\VersionControl etc.

Does anyone have any idea what are the purpose of the clases residing under the VersionControl folder and when|how are they used?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting find. This is news to me to.  They are implemented in certain classes.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Address.php

Scanning over the code and further reading suggests this was part of 'Content Versioning' which was silently dropped for 'Content Staging' feature.

So basically not used. Or not used how intended. They are still implemented.  If you get my point.

Nothing to do with git or svn.

Comment: So...It's basically leftovers

Comment: In summary, yes.  I'm not seeing any evidence it's anything more than that.

Comment: It is used in CustomerRepository:save(). It uses Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\VersionControl\AbstractEntity. I suspect it's a way of tracking if changes were made to the entity to prevent multiple saves inside an application run.